# The code returns 0 GPU when there is a built in GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, cpu, data-processing

was getting started with tensor flow. I dont have any external gpu expect the built in intel 5000. so when I ran this I got 0 . Should that be the desired output? Should I not get 1? If that's the case, should I limit CPU space to ensure it doesn't take much of memory? In that case what should be the approach?

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
len(gpus)
```

The output is 0

for more context, when I tried the following code the output was []

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus: 
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Output:

[]

So here is my code:

```
!pip install tensorflow tensorflow-gpu opencv-python matplotlib
!pip list
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus: 
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

So, incase this is correct how do I Limit CPU memory, and is that necessary

Comment: Built-in Intel GPUs do not have CUDA support so you generally cannot use them for Tensorflow. You need an NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: Intel GPUs are not supported by any DL framework, including TensorFlow.

Answer (score -2):

**You need to use position [0] GPU, meaning your integrated Intel GPU:**

```
    # Check if an integrated Intel GPU is available
    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        # Use the integrated Intel GPU if it is available
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```

**Limiting TensorFlow to be single-threaded would be your best option with an integrated Intel GPU:**

```
# Limit TensorFlow to using a single thread for inter-op and intra-op parallelism
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

Comment: Is this generated by ChatGPT? Because the answer makes no sense.

Comment: TensorFlow does not support Intel integrated GPUs, so there is no position zero to use.

Comment: I wish you would at least research this a bit before commenting... 

https://www.educba.com/tensorflow-opencl/ and https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/opencl-drivers.html

Intel integrated GPUs are supported with TensorFlow via OpenCL.

Comment: That is not part of the standard Tensorflow, its not an official thing.

Comment: I'm not certain where they mentioned they wanted the "official thing" or standard TensorFlow code. They wanted a solution to their problem, and I provided that. When you find this officiality requirement in their post, let me know.

Comment: Look at the tag, it says tensorflow, not something else. And you did not mention this OpenCL thing until I asked, it was clearly not the intention of your answer. And this unofficial Tensorflow has not been updated in more than 2 years, so not even the latest version of Tensorflow is available.